# Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using Access 2010 VBA that is returning a recordset from an IBM iSeries.  I have the following loop to append the recordset to a local table:

```
'Loop through recordset and place values
    Do While rsti401.EOF = False
Set rst401 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblLocal_SL401WK", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
With rst401
    .AddNew
    .Fields("PC") = rsti401.Fields("PC")
    .Fields("TIME") = rsti401.Fields("TIME")
    .Fields("CONO") = rsti401.Fields("CONO")
    .Fields("STYCOL") = rsti401.Fields("STYCOL")
    .Fields("WHSE") = rsti401.Fields("WHSE")
    .Fields("CUNO") = rsti401.Fields("CUNO")
    .Fields("SIZE01") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE01")
    .Fields("SIZE02") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE02")
    .Fields("SIZE03") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE03")
    .Fields("SIZE04") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE04")
    .Fields("SIZE05") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE05")
    .Fields("SIZE06") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE06")
    .Fields("SIZE07") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE07")
    .Fields("SIZE08") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE08")
    .Fields("SIZE09") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE09")
    .Fields("SIZE10") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE10")
    .Fields("SIZE11") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE11")
    .Fields("SIZE12") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE12")
    .Fields("SIZE13") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE13")
    .Fields("SIZE14") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE14")
    .Fields("SIZE15") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE15")
    .Fields("BQTY01") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY01")
    .Fields("BQTY02") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY02")
    .Fields("BQTY03") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY03")
    .Fields("BQTY04") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY04")
    .Fields("BQTY05") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY05")
    .Fields("BQTY06") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY06")
    .Fields("BQTY07") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY07")
    .Fields("BQTY08") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY08")
    .Fields("BQTY09") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY09")
    .Fields("BQTY10") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY10")
    .Fields("BQTY11") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY11")
    .Fields("BQTY12") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY12")
    .Fields("BQTY13") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY13")
    .Fields("BQTY14") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY14")
    .Fields("BQTY15") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY15")
.Update
End With
rsti401.MoveNext
Loop


'close connections
rsti401.Close
rst401.Close
IBM.Close

Set IBM = Nothing
Set rst401 = Nothing
Set rsti401 = Nothing
Set CMD = Nothing
```

However, each time I run it I is stopping at the following line:

```
rst401.Close
```

With error 'Run-time error 91'.  I can't work it out.  I've set rst401 at the beginning, so why am I still getting the error.

Any pointers would be a great help.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Did you state `Dim Rst1401 As New RecordSet` before setting it?

Comment: Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your `rst401` variable evolves ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)). If that doesn't help, then I suggest you see this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would try using a database variable instead of using CurrentDb: Dim dB as Recordset Set dB = CurrentDb. Or move the offending line into the With block.

Comment: One additional note, though not related to your problem. rst401 is opening an entire table, returning records, when all you are trying to do is add a new record. It would be much more efficient to use a where clause that returns not records, or use an insert statement instead of a recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is because the rst401 is set inside the `Do While Loop`, and you are trying to close an object that has lost its scope outside the Loop. Suggest you make the following changes.

```
'Loop through recordset and place values
Set rst401 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblLocal_SL401WK", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Do While rsti401.EOF = False        
    With rst401
        .AddNew
        .Fields("PC") = rsti401.Fields("PC")
        .Fields("TIME") = rsti401.Fields("TIME")
        .Fields("CONO") = rsti401.Fields("CONO")
        .Fields("STYCOL") = rsti401.Fields("STYCOL")
        .Fields("WHSE") = rsti401.Fields("WHSE")
        .Fields("CUNO") = rsti401.Fields("CUNO")
        .Fields("SIZE01") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE01")
        .Fields("SIZE02") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE02")
        .Fields("SIZE03") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE03")
        .Fields("SIZE04") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE04")
        .Fields("SIZE05") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE05")
        .Fields("SIZE06") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE06")
        .Fields("SIZE07") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE07")
        .Fields("SIZE08") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE08")
        .Fields("SIZE09") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE09")
        .Fields("SIZE10") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE10")
        .Fields("SIZE11") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE11")
        .Fields("SIZE12") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE12")
        .Fields("SIZE13") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE13")
        .Fields("SIZE14") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE14")
        .Fields("SIZE15") = rsti401.Fields("SIZE15")
        .Fields("BQTY01") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY01")
        .Fields("BQTY02") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY02")
        .Fields("BQTY03") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY03")
        .Fields("BQTY04") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY04")
        .Fields("BQTY05") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY05")
        .Fields("BQTY06") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY06")
        .Fields("BQTY07") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY07")
        .Fields("BQTY08") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY08")
        .Fields("BQTY09") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY09")
        .Fields("BQTY10") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY10")
        .Fields("BQTY11") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY11")
        .Fields("BQTY12") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY12")
        .Fields("BQTY13") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY13")
        .Fields("BQTY14") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY14")
        .Fields("BQTY15") = rsti401.Fields("BQTY15")
        .Update
    End With
    rsti401.MoveNext
Loop

'close connections
rsti401.Close
rst401.Close
IBM.Close

Set IBM = Nothing
Set rst401 = Nothing
Set rsti401 = Nothing
Set CMD = Nothing
```